# glpsol tool split MIP and LP solutions

Tags: linear-programming, glpk

I am using glpsol to solve a rather big integer optimisation problem. The Simplex algorithm runs for about 30 mins on it, and after that `glpsol` tries to find integer solution using MIP solver.

Question: Can I split this into two steps using only the glpsol command tool, or should I use glpk API ?

I have tried "read" and "nomip" option that according to the documentation is

```
-r filename, --read filename
```

to read the solution from the provided filename rather than to find it with the solver

in this format:

```
 glpsol --cpxlp WhiskasModel.lp --write WhiskasSolution.mip --nomip
```

and after that

```
 glpsol --cpxlp WhiskasModel.lp --read WhiskasSolution.mip
```

but I receive an error:

```
 Reading MIP solution from `WhiskasModel.mip'...
 WhiskasModel.mip:33702: non-integer column valueUnable to read problem solution
```

and it is of course true because WhiskasModel.mip is an LP solution with nonint values.

I find the `glpsol toolkit` rather powerful and I want to play with some MIP options but on each step to wait 30 minutes is rather boring. Can I tell it, "use this LP solution and start MIP" ?

Comment: I don't have an answer to this question since I've never used glpsol, but I'm curious how a commercial LP solver performs on the LP relaxation. 30 minutes! Any chance you could try solving your LP relaxation alone with Gurobi on neos-server.org and report back the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing to try: write the LP basis to a plain text file, and then when re-starting, start with that LP solution as the basis.

Try

```
  -w WhiskasBasis.txt
```

and when restarting to continue on as an IP, ask it to use that basis by adding the `ini` option.

```
--ini WhiskasBasis.txt
```

#### Other suggestions:

1. I wouldn't use the command-line option if you are going to be doing this often. The GLPK API (for your language of choice) and with an IDE, will give you *so* much more flexibility and control. [This link](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GLPK) mentions several.
2. If you post your MIP model formulation with the objective and the constraints (maybe as a different question), you might get suggestions to speed things up. Sometimes there are relaxations and sub-problems that can help tremendously.

Hope that helps.